# Entity Framework, MySQL, SaveChanges - Error in SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

This is the error I am getting:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group) VALUES ('test_user','testpass',13,77,0,0,0,1);SE' at line 9

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group) VALUES ('test_user', 'testpass', 13, 77, 0, 0, 0, 1); SE' at line 9
```

I had a look around and someones explanation that it maybe an issue with the mysql buffer `SELECT is stripped which may indicate some string buffer problems in the MySql drive`

I am using MySQL Connector version 6.5.4.0

Any help appreciated thanks

As requested this is the code I use to insert:

```
public bool CreateMember(string username, string password, int age, int residence)
{
    Context.Members.AddObject(new MemberEntity { Username = username, Password = password, Age = age, Residence = residence, Banned = false, Locked = false, Online = false, Group = 1 });
    return Context.SaveChanges() > 0;
}
```

Comment: The error message tells you the exact cause: A syntax error. Please post the SQL that you executed.

Comment: I added the code to the main page

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue myself, the problem was an outdated MySQL connector on the machine.config, I have since added the following code to my Web.config and it has resolved the issue:

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider"
           invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
           description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL"
           type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.5.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />       
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```